# How to filter activity related to services

Tags: php, mysql

[image: services In databse]

[image: Activity in db]

[image: Mapping of serviceactivity]

PHP

```
<?php include("connect.php");?>
<?php 
    $activityoneid = "select activity.activity_name,activity.activity_id 
                      from activity 
                      join serviceactivitymap on activity.activity_id = serviceactivitymap.activity_id";

    $activityonevalue = $conn->query($activityoneid) or die ($conn>error.__LINE__);
    $activitiesone = [];

    while ($row = $activityonevalue->fetch_assoc()) {
        $activitiesone[] = $row;
    }

    //for services
    $service = "select * from service";
    $servicevalue = $conn->query($service) or die ($conn>error.__LINE__);
    $services = [];

    while ($row = $servicevalue->fetch_assoc()) {
        $services[] = $row;
    }

    foreach($services as $serve)
    {
?> 
        <input type = "checkbox" name = "service" value="<?php echo $serve['service_id']?>">
        <?php echo $serve['service_name']?>
        <br>
        <?php foreach($activitiesone as $activiti)
            {
        ?>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "activity" value = "<?php echo $activiti['activity_id']?>">
            <?php echo $activiti['activity_name'];?>
        <?php 
            } 
        ?>
        <br>
    <?php 
    }?>
```

Here is my code for display service and activity 
       ## Recent Output ## :-
all services display same activity ,can I filter data using service_id means display activity related to service id,if service id = 1 then display only activity related to 1 not others

RECENT OUTPUT:

- Incometax

  - Return Filling
  - Revised Return Filling
  - Tax Payment
  - Statutory Audit
- TDS

  - Return Filling
  - Revised Return Filling
  - Tax Payment
  - Statutory Audit

Expected output:-

- Incometax

  - Return Filling
  - Revised Return Filling
- TDS

  - Tax payment
  - Statutory Audit

see in mapping Third mapping table, I will display Output from mapping table

Thank you

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  If I look at your expected output, for `Incometax` you keep the first value, for `GST` you keep the second, for `TDS` you keep the third.  Is that it?  You want the service index which == the activity index?  If that is it, modify your query `$service` and add `WHERE service_id = activity.activity_id `

Comment: It would be better to show with a diagram or an example what you commented.  You can edit the question, this way it is complete for future readers.

Comment: Sir please check images attached with post....1 st image is services in db,2nd image is activity in db and third is mapping of both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your sample data, I came up with a simpler solution.  Your code is trying do to, in two steps, what the database can do for you.

Your first query gets the services.  Then each associated activity is listed, service by service.  This method, although it works, causes the database to be accessed twice.  The database can do this for you, using SQL.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT s.service_name,     
       a.activity_name
FROM service AS s
JOIN service_has_activity AS sha ON s.service_id  = sha.service_id
JOIN activity             AS a   ON a.activity_id = sha.activity_id
ORDER BY s.service_name, a.activity_name
```

The result is:

```
Incometax     Return Filing
Incometax     Revised Return Filing
TDS           Statutory Audit
TDS           Tax Payment
```

This query uses JOIN to "link" together the `service`, `activity` and `service_has_activity` tables.  Then using ORDER BY sorts the data how you want it.

If you want to filter based on certain conditions, you can add `WHERE` clause(s) in the query.  Ex. if you want to see only the data for a particular service, add this line *before* the `ORDER BY` line:

```
WHERE s.service_name = 'IncomeTax'
```

Then you can code a loop on these results to take care of the display.  It is always more efficient to let the database do these, if it can, and only do the display portion in the PHP code.

The end result is 1 loop (for displaying the results), 1 access to the database (for running the query).  If you have a large data set, it will speed up your page as well.

Comment: Sorry sir but result is same as recent output..I want to add service id in where clause which is the output of value = <?php echo $service['service_id];?>,how i do this

Comment: Same as the "RECENT OUTPUT" or same as the "Expected output" you posted?  I run this on my MySQL here, and I get the result I posted in the answer.

Comment: Your query is correct , I have a problem with where clause what I add in where clause for filter activity related to service

Comment: What filter do you want?  The posted expected result is exactly what the query produces.  The relation between service and activity is defined in the `service_has_activity` table.

Comment: Done sir, I post wrong query , Your query output is correct,Thank u  so much for help

Comment: I added an example of a where clause to my answer.

Comment: can I  ask one more help

Comment: If you want to continue further, you can post a new question, referencing this one.

Comment: unless it is trivial